# Pivot Table: How to sort Month column chronologically

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sort the `Month` column of my pivot table chronologically. In the reference data, I have the `Date` column formated as date and the `Month` column as a date too (using "mmm" format), I get the column sorted, but not grouped (months are repeated for each entry).

I added a helper column `Text Month` using the `TEXT` function (for example for `E2=TEXT(A2, "mmm")` to try to overcome it. Now I am getting a unique column for month values, but not order chronologically. I am showing both pivot tables (one using `Month` and another one using `Text Month` column for the same data set):

[image: Pivot Table sample with Month as column]

Here is the link to my sample:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1If6yur9u86T-ABCJm2NEwhC2y1QgPyHFbv2vHORlZFQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution following the recommendation from [Google Community](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/52562765/pivot-table-google-sheets-how-to-sort-on-month?hl=en), basically, it is using the following formula for getting the Month in order to get the first date of the month, so all dates for a given month have the same date in the `Month` column, so we don't get repeated columns for a month:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,EOMONTH(A2:A,-1)+1))
```

I created a second tab: `Solution` in my sample posted with the question, showing how it works.

Answer (score 2):

After perform some checking, I notice that Google sheet `pivot table` does not provide `custom sort` function like excel pivot table, where you can change the order of the column by moving up or moving down, one solution to present the table as per your expectation, you may create a calculation table as following:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,$F2,$D:$D,G$1)
```

Using the `sumifs` formula, you can still get the output table you wish, although you need to do some working first:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @KinSiang I am trying to follow you base on the screen shoot, but I am not able to figure it out your solution without knowing the row number. Would you update the answer with a screen shot that shows on the left the row number? Tanks

Comment: I move the table so you can understand it better :)

Comment: thank @KinSiang you changed the initial sample. The amount column doesn't have the same values. Anyway, I guess your workaround is to simulate the same result not using a pivot table. In my real example, I need to have a pivot table for other reasons, I didn't include here some filters, I need to filter some results and for this, it is good to have a pivot table.

Comment: Ya, if you must present in pivot table, you can only go to excel for this reason, because Gsheet not providing such function...